# Software controlled variable voltage AC supply with SSR relays

Tags: arduino, voltage, relay, solid-state-relay, autotransformer

I have an autotransformer like this one :

[image: autotransformer]

I would like to control it with an arduino solid state relay like this one:

[image: relay board]

What would happens if I wire every output of the transformer together to the same output and accidentally turn on more than one relay at the same time ?

For example, the 80v, 120v and 150v turned on at the same time would output :

- 80 + 120 + 150 = 350v ?
- (80 + 120 + 150)/3 = 116v ?
- 230v because this is the maximum input ?

Would it be dangerous ? I don't really understand how an autotransformer work. Any idea how I could achieve it safely ?

Comment: I think you mean that you are contemplating wiring each output of the transformer to one contact on a relay, and the opposite contacts of each relay are connected together to your circuit output?  If so then turning on more than one relay at a time will short the relevant autotransformer outputs together, which is a Bad Thing.

Comment: Yes. I currently have the autotransformer working with a relay board like [this one](https://www.14core.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/8-Channel-Relay-Module-Wiring-Pinout-Diagram2.jpg), which suits better because every relay has 2 possible outputs (opened one vs closed one), not just on/off.

Comment: If you source the transformer with 230V/50Hz (or 60Hz); the magnatic field induces all windings which of them are all galvanically connected.  so when you accidentally short two terminals, a short-circuit current would break your fuse!

Comment: @MrH: You have managed to dis-improve your post by eliminating the photos and replacing them with links. Can you put them back?

Comment: Sorry I found the photos to be very big and annoying. Your schematic is much more relevant.

Comment: No, the photos are fine and show exactly what we're dealing with without the need to follow two links. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will be shorting secondary transformer windings, which will produce a current that is only limited by resistive losses in your circuit and it is extremely likely to burn something. Just blow a fuse or open a breaker, if you are lucky.

Make sure to never activate more than one relay/switch at a time (preferably with hardware not just software), and perhaps add fuses for safety.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are trying to make a software-controlled variable voltage AC supply but using SSRs rather than regular relays with changeover contacts. As you have realised, the mechanical contacts allow wiring in such a way that a short circuit is impossible in the event of two relays turning on at the same time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK2qAg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Relay ladder. The highest voltage wins. (b) SSR single-pole switches. Nobody wins.*

To use your SSR solution you would need to be confident that:

- Your logic is bullet-proof and that no two SSRs could be on simultaneously.
- Be confident in the reliability of the SSRs to prevent one failing on and remaining on when another is switched on.
- Be confident that the relay module will not blink all the SSRs on power-up.

Be very clear in your understanding that turning on two at the same time will short-circuit the windings between those outputs.

---

From the comments:

> Unfortunately I cannot guarantee that only one relay will be switched on at the same time, especially at boot time of the raspberry in control of the board where all the GPIO are turned on all together for a very short time (1 sec maybe). What would you suggest to make it work safely with an SSR board ?

If I **had** to use SSRs then I would look for some way to disable them until the Pi is stable. Off-hand I can't think of a way that won't suffer the same power-up pulse problem that your existing arrangement would. Perhaps an on-delay timer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this is exactly what I'm trying to do: fig (a) is what I have today whereas fig (b) is what I was thinking to do. Unfortunately I cannot guarantee that only one relay will be switched on at the same time, especially at boot time of the raspberry in control of the board where all the GPIO are turned on all together for a very short time (1 sec maybe).
What would you suggest to make it work safely with an SSR board ?

Comment: See the update. I recommend that you un-accept for a day or two as it encourages more answers and you may get some other insights and solutions. Then pick the best!